# Strange DateTime.ToString behavior

Tags: .net, datetime-format

I have the following line of code inside of a function:

```
String value = endDate.Value.ToString(dateFormatStr);
//endDate is a DateTime? object (returned from a LINQ to SQL query).
```

In the particular instance I am experiencing odd behavior, the value of endDate is {10/2/2010 12:00:00 AM}. Here's my results:

dateFormatStr="d" => value="10/2/2010" (I would expect "2")
dateFormatStr="M" => value="October 2" (I would expect "10")

Comment: Please note, I do not want "dd" or "mm". I don't want my results 0-padded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to put a "%" in front of the format when using a single character custom format that matches a standard format. For example:

```
endDate.Value.ToString("%d");
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers

Answer (score 3):

Your result agreed with the [microsoft specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Use the relative [DateTime properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.datetime_properties%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) in order to get Day, Month and Year

****Edited****

Check this code to see how the 'd' character changes its behaviour depending on it is alone or it is part of a pattern string

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

// 'd' is part of a pattern expression: "d "
MessageBox.Show(time.ToString("d "));
// result: "24 "

// 'd' defines a specific pattern: "short date"
MessageBox.Show(time.ToString("d"));
//result : "24/08/2010"
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I checked in your page and i noticed my previous answer was not complete. The page you provided said the true. You can test the new code to proove it by yourself (i hope it works)

Comment: Thanks for your update. Yes, the d with the space after it works as does the "%d" which I've indicated below.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this site](http://dotnetperls.com/datetime-format).

This is not irregular at all, in fact you are using the single-character standard formats ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)) for dates.

If you are wanting to split your formats in the way you are expecting them, either use `dd` and `MM`, or (if this is what you need to do) rather just take the integer value from the `DateTime` object.

I.e:

```
endDate.Value.Day
endDate.Value.Month
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the format strings wrong. Try "dd" and "MM".

Answer (score 0):

Some patterns has some kind of short name - single character name, which is the same as used in full patterns, but unfortunately has different meaning. You just have discovered that.

This is another [site](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) which can be useful.